# Excluding some properties when doing JsonConvert.DeserializeObject on request basis

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I have the following 2 classes inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
public class Details4
{
    public Details4()
    {

        this.RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD = new List<RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD>();
    }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string RESOURCENAME { set; get; }
    [Display(Name = "Account Name")]
    [Required]
    public string ACCOUNTNAME { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "Resource type")]
    [Required]
    public string RESOURCETYPE { set; get; }


    public List<RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD> RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD { set; get; }
}
public class RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD
{
    public string CUSTOMLABEL { set; get; }
    public string CUSTOMVALUE { set; get; }
}
```

now i am doing the following deserialization , as follow:-

```
resourceAccountListInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details4>(json);
```

but in some scenarios i am not interested to deserialize the whole RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD list. while on other i need to deserizlize the RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD list. so is there a way to exclude some properties from the Deserialization process ? i know i can use `[JsonIgnore]` at the class level , but this will always exclude the related component,, while i am trying to find a way to do this on some methods only ,,, so is there a way to exclude some properties inside this line of code ??:-

```
resourceAccountListInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details4>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is conditionally serializing object members.
Json.NET has this feature . You have to define a public method named ShouldSerialize{MemberName} returning a boolean value.

```
   public bool ShouldSerializeINSERT_YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME_HERE() {return true; // you can use some condition here}
```

Comment: Check this url 

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm

Comment: Also this url

[link](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/04/15/conditionally-serializing-fields-and-properties-with-jsonnet)